# How can I implement Select and Count in Hibernate using criteria

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm new using hibernate, I have query like :

```
select count(1) from (
SELECT COUNT (1)
FROM USR_BASE
WHERE ST_CD = 1
group by USR_NO)
```

How can I implement that query in Hibernate using criteria ?

Because, I already implement with method :

```
public int totalUser(UsrBase usrBase) {
    Criteria criteria = createCriteria();
    String stCd = usrBase.getStCd();
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList())
            .add(Projections.property("usrNo"))
            .add(Projections.property(stCd))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("usrNo")));

    return((Long)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

}

the result not same with my query... Please help me.

Comment: your sql query isn't so clear as what exactly you are trying to achieve. There is no point of using group by as at the end your are counting entire result.

Comment: Agree with the above comment.  Your query makes no sense, so there is no point to asking about Criteria syntax.

Comment: how about this ? select count(*) from (
select usr_mgnt_no 
from igib_usr_base 
where st_cd = 1 group by usr_mgnt_no)

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(1) from (
SELECT COUNT (1)
FROM USR_BASE
WHERE ST_CD = 1
group by USR_NO)
```

I think it will be more easily with

```
select count(distinct(USR_NO)) from USR_BASE WHERE ST_CD = 1
```

Comment: i am glad it help.